# Is mocking the Indian English used by a user abusive?

Tags: discussion, support, declined-flags, code-of-conduct, abuse

I found a question on main about a memory error which used almost perfect grammar and was completely clearly phrased, but it included a term along the lines of

> one file has 5 lakh lines

It was quickly settled in comments that [a lakh means 100 000 in Indian English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_English#Numbering_system) which is evident from a quick google search.

Some time later (but with the explanation that "lakh" is a real word still visible in the comments) a user posted a comment along the lines of

> Add 3 boobla memory to your computer.

As far as technical aspects go this comment is completely unhelpful, but socially speaking it's clearly mocking the asker for their use of Indian English. (Let's ignore now that the first google hit for "boobla" is horrible racial slur, this was probably not intentional.)

I flagged the comment as "harassment, bigotry or abuse", because mocking someone for their use of English (and valid use of Indian English) is exactly the kind of put-down that the whole welcome wagon is about. The comment didn't contain any actual technical help, so it was only posted to take a jab at the asker. The comment was soon deleted, but later I noticed that my flag was declined. As far as I know only mods can decline comment flags.

So I don't understand. If it was an appropriate comment, why did it get deleted? If it was inappropriate, why was my flag declined? Is it inappropriate, but only a little? Is *some* amount of non-constructive mockery allowed towards users? Did the moderator make a mistake or am I wrong?

---

Just a quick note on timings: the question was posted today at around 9 AM UTC, the comment was posted sometime after 10 AM UTC, I flagged it at 10:19 AM.

Comment: Timestamps are likely key, I bet, as that would be a pretty abusive comment, indeed.  Was the comment several years old?

Comment: @fbueckert brand new.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what would be the case.  I do know that mods generally decline such flags to old comments, but still delete the comment, so I thought that might be the scenario.

Comment: I guess the moderator was unaware that lakh was valid Indian English, and that the user was just mocking a nonsense word instead of valid Indian English. That's still _unkind_ in my opinion, but not harassment, bigotry or abuse. That flag is reserved for severe cases

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I know what a lakh is. I didn't realise that the term referenced was a racial slur.

Comment: @ChrisF as I said I don't think the racial slur is intended, I'd guess that the commenter intended to post gibberish but failed.

Comment: That is indeed offensive, especially given the extremely offensive slang meaning of the word "boobla" (found via quick google search - urban dictionary)

Comment: I've spent some time on the internet and have seen my share of pixels, but I've never heard of that UD definition. UD isn't exactly the OD. Note, boobla is the name of an ebay competitor. Maybe. It appears to be broked, anyhow.

Comment: I agree with the spirit of this post. However, there is [some disagreement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333867/meta-to-new-user-your-question-is-a-turd-that-cannot-be-polished-or-we-need-t) on whether it is reasonable for all English speakers to learn all localised units of measurement (e.g. lakhs and crores). I think it is probably helpful to let speakers of Indian English know that this might not be well understood outside of their territory.

Comment: Put another way, if a post uses terms that need to be "googled", then it needs clarification.

Comment: No, condescending comments are not permitted.

Comment: @halfer an edit or even a gentle suggestion to change that phrasing would've been fine. Mocking without actually helping anything (including clarification) would not.

Comment: I am an Indian, and I found that comment rather funny! People need to learn to take a joke sometime. Also Imagine if everyone started using nomenclature from their own language and other users having to google them to get the relevant meaning. In all fairness its a 'hindi' word, but it has been anglicised too. lakh -> lac. but still the most PC approach IMHO would be to just update/edit that to a number(maybe by a fellow user), instead of you know. Also lets cut some slack to the guy, He might not have intended to hurt OP's feels just might have tried to keep the discussion in a lighter vein.

Comment: While it's great you found it funny, and I admit there are comments on this site I find funny too, even if it hurts one person's feelings or makes them feel unwelcome, it's still bad.

Comment: @Tas Ok, let me get this straight,I'm all against rude behaviour would never justify that,but we need to draw the line somewhere of what is rather acceptable and what isn't,& this thing here IMHO didn't deserve all that outrage.The site is already so formal,Lets not make it any more bland,and keep the humour flowing.&Please don't even get me started on the "Indian English" part there is no such thing,Either its English or it isnt.(not referring to accent),cause if you tell me that is a thing,I swear to GOD I'mma start using "gooblieballs" everywhere cause it means good question In "my english"

Comment: Slight aside: research into the origins of "needful" is interesting...

Comment: OK, M leaving this discussion, One last thing, It was as simple as, OP had used an "unknown" unit and the comment-er provided solution in an equally unknown unit, I'm almost sure he didn't intend the racial slur thingy, it was just a bad coincidence. People are drawing a little too much of conclusions here. Case closed. :)

Comment: @Tas "even if it hurts one person's feelings or makes them feel unwelcome, it's still bad." That's a rather slippery slope, I think. Could anyone who disagrees with you not argue that your comment makes them feel unwelcome? Would that be reason to flag it as abuse? What about people who feel unwelcome because answerers refuse to do their homework for them? I'm not saying overt rudeness should be acceptable, but I do think there's a difference between rudeness and poor judgement, and how a case should be handled should depend on more than just whether it hurts one person's feelings.

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib SE have already discussed the issue of humour: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/ and Indian English most definitely is a "thing": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_English In fact a main feature of the Indian English dialect is that it generally uses the Indian numbering system: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system

Comment: @AaronF Ok then, Lets ask everyone to start learning it asap, or else you never know, who might end up feeling hurt.

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib if only it were possible to stop oneself from posting rude comments without having to learn all of the dialects of English that exist..

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib Considering British English and American English are also "things", and both also have specific words that the others don't have (At least British English has words I don't hear in American English) and use, I would most certainly say that Indian English is a thing and perfectly acceptable. It just defines which dialect of English we're talking about. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I had never heard of anyone denying the existence of different dialects of English before now.

Comment: Denying the existence outright is one thing, and arguing that if all dialects should be normal on the SO is a different thing, I used it "being a thing" on SO's context read how I give an example of posting a question, but no issues, maybe you misunderstood me due to my different "dialect" get it!!!! Ohh... the irony :D

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib you're the only one raising the whole discussion that all dialects of English are normal on SO. By "raising" I mean denying, but nobody claimed what you're trying to refute.

Comment: @Andras Deak - It was not Mohd Abdul Mujib who was "raising the whole discussion that all dialects of English are normal", quite the contrary, he wrote "the most PC approach IMHO would be to just update/edit that to a number" and "Denying the existence outright is one thing, and arguing that if all dialects should be normal on the SO is a different thing". It was Kendra who wrote "I would most certainly say that Indian English is a thing and perfectly acceptable."

Comment: Regarding to "boobla": The only reference to a "racial slur" found in the first few google hits is in the urban dictionary. Hardly a reliable source. _All_ other occurences (and there are many!) are completely harmless. I would be a bit more cautios when issuing statements like "boobla is a very very bad word". It even isn't the top definition in that dictinonary (this one is again completely harmless), but as I said, UD is not an authority at all.

Comment: @Ctx I'd also add that pretty much anything found on UD would be some sort of slur or bizarre sex act (that can, in turn, be used as an insult). Moreover, UD has A LOT of stuff in it, most feature common words/phrases or something that can be very easily made up by anybody (e.g., "boobla"). I know *some* stuff is "real"  but I feel like some 13 year olds just made up a lot of the entries from scratch. So, yeah - hardly an authority. If you find something in UD it doesn't even mean it's seriously used anywhere around the world. At best might be an inside joke between a group.

Comment: @Armali sorry, I didn't phrase that comment very well, because I wrote it an an annoyed haste. What I meant was that Mohd Abdul Mujib has been trying to convince us that it's not OK to use words specific to Indian English on SO, whereas nobody has claimed that it is. The discussion is not about whether such region-specific words should be left: they shouldn't. The discussion is about being a jerk in comments. And anyone reading my question should see this, hence my annoyance.

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib In my English, "gooblieballs" are how leggie Rashid Khan gets most of his wickets ;)

Comment: Maybe it's due to my lakh of understanding, but I thought the word "boobla" was just a "hoopla" with the "b" from another word. Context does changes meanings I guess.

Comment: @toon Haahahha LMFAO, who is he though, haven't kept up with cricket lately. Watched a few ipl matches but don't have much time lately to watch sports.

Comment: He's an Afghani bowler. Me either, he's just who popped up as notable when I googled 'googly' to see who's current. My point being how from England to Africa, India, Australia my comment is perfectly comprehensible, but might be objected to or edited on 'regional' grounds..

Comment: I hate the welcome wagon, you as the OP are well-aware of this and typically on the same side of the "really? this is what your focused on?!" part of the fence as me. So as part of a culture whose words are many times taken out of context or not understood by those "outsiders" - I looked at this. Flagging was the right call. I asked several, it was more than 5, Indian colleagues (yeah, Andras just for you :) and they were all offended - I have no other reasoning but to agree than cause its not my culture and I will listen to those whose culture it is.

Comment: If askers are expected to do a quick google search about a good question, its only reasonable that a responder does a quick google search to see if there response is offensive.

Comment: Comment is rude, The only argument I can find is : When facing an unknow term from a foreign language that sneak into a conversation, I can use weird sound to show the speaker I didn't understand the word without spending time trying to prononce something I didn't understand. Especially when I sneak a word of Xhosa. No one every try to repeat those.

Answer (score 145):

*Flag handling aside...*

Yes, this is rude.

It would have been rude before the Great Unwelcoming. (And the "Summer of Love" before that.) That is irrelevant.

It is rude whether or not the comment-maker, the flagger, or any readers were aware (I wasn't) that "boobla" has a particular insulting meaning.

It's trying to humiliate someone; it has absolutely no constructive purpose. It does not belong here.

The end.

Comment: Indeed. Also, Indian English is an official dialect of English, it's perfectly valid. It's a shame some people choose to mock others rather than take an opportunity to educate themselves. Something I don't expect to see on a site that's all about sharing knowledge :-(

Comment: Actually, that's another good point: the "Indian English" part is **also irrelevant** to whether this is rude or not.

Comment: Except it's not "the end." Because categorizing it as abuse or not has consequences for the user's standing in the community.

Comment: It's true, @jpmc26: I used the word "rude" and meant exactly that, whereas the question does ask about "abuse". There is a real gap between the two, and your answer makes a good point addressing the actual wording of the question.

Comment: I now realize that I'm strongly biased by the _old_ flag system, where we had "harmless but useless" (no longer needed, too chatty) vs. rude/abusive. In those days I didn't have to think twice when I saw someone being a jerk. And that's probably part of the reason why I categorize this as "abusive" language. This might just again show that we're all the worse off now that we have to measure hostile intentions on a precision scale.

Comment: Yeah, it does seem that there's piled far too much burden of precisely identifying, categorizing, and labelling in almost every aspect of moderation here. At least we still have nice simple up/down votes.

Comment: My point is exactly that we have more options. We (almost) all agree here that the comment had to be deleted because it was rude. In the Old Days (an eon of a year ago) this would've been a clear-cut flag (rude/abusive) and no mod would've thought to weigh the _category_ of the flag. Now in the Brave New Days we have to weigh the level of jerkness of a comment. Is it merely "unkind" (whatever that means), or is it rude? Actually, jpmc26's point is that it _is_ rude, but it's not "harassment, bigotry or abuse". Is "rude" stronger than "unfriendly or unkind"? I might think so, others might not.

Comment: Gotcha, @AndrasDeak, somehow I got your intent backwards the first time I read the comment.

Answer (score 67):

I handled the flag.

I didn't search for the term used because a) I'm at work and b) I thought that the comment  was unkind, but didn't warrant the abuse flag.

I did, however, agree that the comment should be deleted.

I now see that that may have been a mistake.

If there could be any doubt about what you're flagging a custom flag is probably the best route rather than one of the standard flags.

Comment: Thanks. For what it's worth it crossed my mind that I might have used a custom flag instead–two seconds after I left the abusive one.

Comment: Hm, even under the impression that "lakh" was a nonsense word, I would disagree with the decline. A comment that has the *sole purpose* of humiliating someone for their lack of English skills should be harassment. It's not like this was snark mixed with some attempt to help or educate, but purely trolling OP.

Comment: @BaummitAugen No, I didn't think "lakh" was a nonsense word - I know it's a number. It's the *other* word we're talking about here.

Comment: @ChrisF Okay, but that does not change my point. The comment was still posted with no intent other than mocking OP for their non-"western" English.

Comment: @Andras I could also see someone who hadn't heard of "lakh" thinking the OP was trying to be funny and they were trying to be sarcastically humourous back. Text is difficult though - especially if you might be making up a stupid word in your response that turns out can mean something else... unless there's a lot more context it's a little difficult to assert it's definitely bigotry or abusive.

Comment: @JonClements by the time the comment was posted there was the first comment asking what a lakh is, and the second comment (mine) explaining what it is.

Comment: @ChrisF Since I'm not currently clear on it from your answer, could you clarify: did you 1) like Andras, conclude that the comment was clearly meant to mock the asker for their dialect, but decide that such mockery wasn't sufficient to justify a harassment/bigotry/abuse flag, OR 2) think the intent of the comment was some specific other thing (in which case, what?) OR 3) not read any specific intent into the comment at all? As it stands, you suggest that your choice may have been a mistake, but it's not clearly what *precisely* the mistake was, and I think it'd be interesting to know.

Comment: Is there a feature request here? it sounds bad that a useful flag gets declined due to the flag type being tied to some specific consequence to the user where you judge they should have the benefit of the doubt. Maybe the system should have a way to accept the user's flag as helpful, but let the mod choose whether to apply the consequence.

Comment: @NathanHughes There's a bigger issue here, and personally it's the reason I am careful about comment flag types: these are all recorded, and I'm 99% sure we're going to see stats per flag type in another "we need to be more welcoming" blog post. Thus, I find it very important that we're accurate in handling these flags. That's all aside from this specific case; I *probably* would have deleted the comment/marked the flag helpful.

Comment: @Undo The flipside to that, of course, is that if you are "careful" about handling flag types then looking at the comments that attracted accepted "unkind" flags ceases to be a useful way of assessing the community's sense of what is unkind; instead, it mostly measures the judgement of the moderators.

Comment: @MarkAmery Trust me, the community's sense of what is flag-worthy in *any* category is pretty terrible.

Comment: @Undo Are you insulting the community?!?!1! *[Immediately flags Undo's comment as containing harassment, bigotry, or abuse.]*

Comment: @MarkAmery, i once told an user: "DBA is a real job. Don't add index on every column and every table trying to speed up the query." with 3 link to Real MSDN article and SQL Guru article about this bad practice. I saw 2 member arguing to mods that it was harassement. Beeing rejected before I got the Nice "Be nice notice."

Comment: Barring the specific word in question, you did the right thing. Don't change your mind.

Comment: This is an awful lot of hand wringing over a single comment.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Yep, I think it's a whole load of hullabaloo [*crosses fingers that's not a racial slur*]. Basically, this was an unintentional error, mods aren't walking dictionaries, but now everyone's going to be more careful. I don't think we *need* a community discussion on the issue. That should be reserved for instances where moderation *willfully* permits what a user considers abuse / rudeness, not the case here. An *extra* custom mod flag with a dictionary definition would have sufficed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey This seems pretty typical of any post asking why (or even just whether) something is offensive: Several answers covering the options of 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes, but...', and 'You can't tell without context; use a custom flag', the inevitable "People need to learn to take a joke" comment, the rude vs abusive discussion, intent, and the discussion over what should happen with flags like this in the specific case and in general. If anything, there's a lot less arguing over whether this is offensive, probably because this case involves an actual slur.

Comment: @BSMP: ChrisF is being rather generous.  If I'd been the moderator who fat-fingered the original comment flag, I wouldn't have even bothered to respond to this post.  This is the world we now live in, where folks can't work out for themselves what is offensive and what isn't or what flag to use, partly because we've legislated it to death.

Comment: @RobertHarvey in that case I count myself lucky that ChrisF handled my flag. I'm a bit surprised by your attitude because the kind of subtle put-downs the new CoC is trying to fight come exactly "a single comment" at a time. And since the whole welcoming baggage started it hasn't been trivial at all what the userbase considers acceptable and what it doesn't. We are a community, and frankly I'd expect a moderator to be more supportive of the community trying to figure out what's right and what's wrong (and welcome that for once people agree).

Comment: Here's how supportive I am.  Despite my misgivings that the community is turning stack overflow into a troubleshooting forum, I accede to their wishes and moderate accordingly.  This is a post about a single comment, the outcome of which should really be obvious to everyone, and the disproportionate amount of attention that it has gotten just wastes everyone's time, though I suppose it's their time to waste.  See also Parkinson's Law of Triviality (aka what color should we paint the nuclear reactor's toolshed).

Comment: *and welcome that for once people agree* @AndrasDeak Right? We didn't even get any of the free speech, "this is the end of Stack Overflow", or "it's rude but they deserve it" crowd this time.

Comment: @BSMP Nice swipe, but I assume those folks simply didn't feel that this post was worth their time, especially when people mischaracterize their intentions.

Comment: @Robert single comment or not what is interesting is to understand difference of "unfriendly" and "abusive" and even more important should a mod decline an abusive flag when they just think it's unfriendly? If so we better get a really good guidance related to this.

Comment: @PetterFriberg: Use this simple metric: if you wouldn't want it printed in the newspaper so that your mother or grandmother would see it in print, then you probably shouldn't say it.

Comment: hmm @RobertHarvey I'm not really following you (how is your comment related to mine), is this another rorschach test?

Comment: @PetterFriberg: No.  But I think you just made my point.  Perhaps it's because I grew up in a different era, but back then people *knew* when they were being rude.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I really hope you don't feel I was being rude, I was trying to make you smile (rorschach=people see what they see), anyway if you feel so I'm sorry and you are free to delete my previous comment. My previous point was that the comment flag was "at least" unfriendly, so I was curious whether a mod should decline an abusive flag on it. *I thought that the comment was unkind, but didn't warrant the abuse flag*

Comment: *That was what I taught was interesting about this meta post and maybe worth a discussion, single comment or not.*

Comment: @PetterFriberg: Ah, no worries.  That's the problem, in a nutshell, with all forms of electronic communication (social media, email, etc); you can't read the person's face, body language or tone of voice.

Answer (score 14):

In this case, in context, and on reflection, it would seem to be rude and inappropriate, yes.

But it takes a moment to be sure of that. Out of context the comment just uses a nonsense term and it's not immediately evident that it has been employed both *deliberately* and as a reference to what the author rudely misinterpreted as another nonsense term.

As such, I would have raised a custom flag on this explaining that, beyond reasonable doubt, this was a mickey-take of the OP's use of the term "lakh". I wouldn't expect a standard flag to have gained much traction here.

And I still think that as far as "abuse" goes this is very much on the lower end of the spectrum.

Answer (score 13):

This answer is written, as the OP requested, without regard to whether the word in question is a vulgar racial slur. That fact changes the situation significantly, so my purpose here is *only* to address the more general question of whether mocking someone's language is "abuse."

---

- Is mocking helpful? No.
- Is mocking in good taste? No, not usually.
- Is mocking allowed here? No.
- Should the comment have been deleted according to site rules and/or community guidelines? Yes.
- Is it rude? Probably somewhat. There are cases where people who are familiar with each other mock each other as a form of enjoyable banter, but it's likely not possible for the author to know that the person would be receptive.
- But is it *abuse*? No, not unless done persistently over time.

Abuse, when used to describe the actions of a person, is a *very* strong word in the English language. The connotation is that severe harm has been done. A single distasteful joke does not meet that high standard. A reasonable person can be expected to roll their eyes or make a disgusted face and move on if they dislike it.

Are we going to be a community that categorizes every possible offense as "abuse"? Or are we going to be a little more reasonable? It's fine if we want to be a community that prides itself on respect, but that can't mean that we treat every offense as something severe that should be punished with extreme prejudice. A community like that is untenable.

For a comment that's inappropriate but not abusive, choose one of the other flag reasons. "It's unfriendly or unkind," is probably applicable and less severe. I've used "It's no longer needed," on comments I believed were only slightly over the line to much success and still think this is an appropriate use of it. And a custom flag will allow you to explain if you don't feel like it fits in any of the others.

Comment: Thanks for ignoring the slur, I'm still certain that it's a red herring here. As for "abuse", you're probably right, I'm not completely clear on the exact subtleties of English around these terms. If it makes any difference I meant less "abuse" _per se_, more "abusive language". This might not make an actual difference. I'll have to think about your point regarding what constitutes abuse. Reasonable people can be expected to roll their eyes and move on from a _lot_ of crap thrown at them on the internet. But there's only so much pushback one can take if they face it all the time.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I don't think there's any real difference between the notions of "abuse" and "abusive language." The latter came about as the concept of language and words over long periods of time (e.g., daily to your children) also having the capacity to cause damage. I would rather distinguish between abusive (blatantly extreme, insulting, and probably vulgar), rude (insulting but not extreme), and merely inappropriate (disrespectful but probably not intended to be harmful). I think most jokes like this would fall into the latter category.

Comment: I like your answer bit I still doubt SE intention was for us to get perfect hit rate, they know well that for some it's abusive, for some unfriendly and for some just no longer need. I don't think they taught mods would decline an abusive flag because the mod just think it's unfriendly. Hence what ever flag Andras raised it should have been approved

Comment: @PetterFriberg No because labeling something as abusive has long term consequences for the user's standing.

Comment: So it's better for the user to not be unfriendly since some users will judge it as abusive. We will never be able to establish the exact difference (as for other flags VLQ vs NAA). On some comments all flags will be more or less valid depending on culture/backround etc.if this has long term consequences for a single user, suspended but they where "Just unfriendly" they will have to discuss this with mods .

Comment: *AFIK There is no automatic rep penalty nor automatic suspension (as for flags on question), hence mod before suspension will see all the comments flagged as they where written and I doubt that the actual flag is of great importance*

Comment: @PetterFriberg Labeling things as more severe than they are to scare people and saying it's okay because people should always be perfect is dishonest and ultimately harmful. It's a tactic used by extremists. Do you not realize that this issue is couched in the larger cultural debate about speech rights? Labeling something as "abusive" or "hate speech" is just a tactic used to justify control.

Answer (score 11):

This is just my take, so feel free to disagree!

The problem with discussions surrounding flags is that there is often lack of context.

You are making an assumption that the commenters mocking is only related to the language of the OP. While the commenter is mocking the OP, based on what you provided in this question, we have no way of knowing if that is the only thing being mocked.

Thus, lack of context.

IMO, a flag should definitely be raised for comments like that. I just wouldn't mark it as "harassment, bigotry or abuse", because claims like that need substantiation, not assumptions. It was an unhelpful, and **potentially** distasteful comment.

Save the "harassment, bigotry or abuse" flags for clear cut cases so the validity of that flag can remain somewhat useful.

Comment: The one detail you didn't seem to consider is that moderators have context. The only reason the kind audience on meta doesn't have context is that I wanted to spare the owner of the question from the meta effect.

Comment: Im not referring to the flagging, I'm referring to this question. We don't have context. Marking someone/something as Abusive or what have you and then asking if its okay without providing full unbiased context is unhelpful.

Comment: OK, your penultimate paragraph confused me. You wrote "I just wouldn't mark it as »harassment, bigotry or abuse«, because claims like that need substantiation, not assumptions". This seems to concern moderators and the person raising the flag, both of whom have full context.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I think what I was aiming for is that given the context I have here, I would not agree with your flag.

Answer (score 2):

The comment is condescending and rude, so at an absolute minimum it qualifies as "unfriendly or unkind."

In my opinion, it *is* abusive because it "attacks a person or group." That kind of comment is intrinsically mocking *anyone* who uses Indian English, which is kind of the definition of attacking a group (especially given that, as you mention, that's actually a perfectly correct thing to say).