# Is it appropriate to edit a post to not use dialect specific terminology?

Tags: discussion, edits, languages

This is in a way a follow up question to "[Is mocking the Indian English used by a user abusive?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379045/is-mocking-the-indian-english-used-by-a-user-abusive)", and made in light of [an answer and comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/333819#333819) given in "[Advice for non-native English speakers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers)".

[In the past](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53755146/revisions) I have edited questions that use the term "lakh" to instead be explicitly written as a number, and the term "crore" to instead be written in millions. For those unaware:

> 1 lakh = 10<sup>5</sup> = one hundred thousand
>
> 1 crore = 10<sup>7</sup> = ten million

So, I would make the following edits (as per the example linked):

> 5 lakh => 500,000
>
> 35 crore => 350 million

As editors, should we be changing these local terms to be dialect-agnostic to assist with other users answering the question, add footnotes that explain the conversion, or allow them verbatim in order to preserve the intent and avoid errors in conversion/translation?

---

*Yes, I am aware I used a dialect specific notation for thousands separators (',') which is a different character in many countries ('.'), and yes I'm aware of the irony of this*

Comment: I am not really clear on which notation would be _dialect-agnostic_ here..

Comment: Why is this complicated?  We're all programmers here, programming languages don't know beans about lakh, crore or thousand-separators either.  Just use the notation appropriate for the language tag.

Comment: I wouldn't go seeking them out, but if you happen to find a question or answer that uses uncommon terminology (doesn't have to be crore or lakh) I don't personally see a problem editing it to make it clearer.

Comment: Related, from a long while back, on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108425/

Comment: We ask users to post in English, so there is no place for Lakhs or crores, or whatever unit there might be. No shame in editing those out.

Comment: Should we write "five dozen" or "three score"? Just joking, but there are lots of units that are in use in some regions, but not (or no longer) widely known on a global scale. We've mostly got users with some level of engineering background here, so SI units and their quantifying prefixes should be understood by most, just like the most common English names for the powers of 10. Everything else may need clarification.

Comment: @Luuklag The problem is, that "_lakh_" and "_crore_" are English.

Comment: @Teemu, to some they are, not to the majority.

Comment: @Luuklag to a rough estimate, [India has 125x10^6 English speakers, the second most after the USA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_English-speaking_population). While it is technically true that this makes them not a majority, they are not a *tiny* minority by any means.

Comment: @Luuklag *We ask users to post in English* — but *which* English? We don't go around editing "aluminium" to "aluminum" or vice versa. In fact, it turns out people often get really angry when you change such things! That's only for "simple" changes between two widely recognized English dialects.

Comment: Is it appropriate to change gallons and ounces to non-dialect units?

Comment: @Shepmaster How many of the english speakers of india contribute to SO? I never heard of "lakh" or "crore" outside of posts on SO before - and it was not part of my english curriculum

Comment: @PatrickArtner [quite a lot](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey), judging by the the Stack Overflow survey from 2018. I'd also expect many terms on Stack Overflow weren't covered in any one person's English curriculum. And that's assuming that people paid attention on their classes; even for widely accepted things like capitalizing proper nouns.

Comment: @Shepmaster well - english or English vs. 500.000 or 5 lakh .. but thanks for the snide comment. About 14 % [correct link](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018) of the survey answers were from india - this is not insubstantial but the other 86% might not quite get what those words mean. But it seems it is used all over southern asia as well .. so if you are happy adressing only 50-60% of the english speakers on SO it is fine to use it.

Comment: Or use the scientific prefixes! 5 lakh -> 500 k ! That also avoids the use of locale-dependent thousand separators. 35 crore -> 350 M . Oh, and never heard of those before the linked post on meta. I remember refraining from using US/UK slang words, or editing those I see, for people not familiar with them. I agree with the answers suggesting editing those.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I can't explain the link oddity, it's the first result on Google and it displays on mobile, but copying it doesn't work. The aside about proper capitalization was intended to have a smiley, but got lost in my scramble to try and edit the link on mobile, my apologies. For what it's worth, I'm **in favor** of the proposed edits, I just want it to be justified for good reasons, not "my English dialect is better than another one" or "half of the users of SO are meaningless".

Comment: @Shepmaster, the aluminium example is something completely different. There is no need to google either of those terms for anyone familiar with the english language. But if you are talking about 5 lakh of code how is anyone not familiar with Indian English supposed to know what is meant here. It also shows poor ettiquette from anyone using such terms in their Q's. As you want your question to be easily understandable for the entire SO audience, also for non native english users. Hence you should simply refrain from such niche wording and use mainstream accepted terms.

Answer (score 17):

If the language is likely to confuse users, then it should be edited to the least-confusing terminology.  Lakh and Crore are a good example of this; while Indian users will be familiar with these terms, other speakers (both English and non-English speakers) will not be, so they should be converted, when the number has some relevance to the question.

If the terminology is either not relevant to the question, or not likely to confuse users, then it should be left as is.  Things like dialect-specific spelling ("Color" vs "Colour"), variable names, etc. should be left as is.  Crore/Lakh should be left if they're part of a title on a report, for example, or an example in a where clause, or similar.

There is some room for flexibility here, and I think the error should be on the side of making the change.

Some examples:

> I have a database with about 15 Cr. records, which I want to query ...

That definitely should be changed, as it's a core element of the question (the user must understand how many records the table has to properly answer)

But the question:

> My database has these variables ... "income_crore"

Should definitely not be changed, as it's just a variable name and not relevant to the question to know what Crore is.

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion, yes it is appropriate to edit to something to be 'dialectic-agnostic'. It reduces the chance of other words from coming in too like the Japanese Man (10,000) or other counters from other languages. I would venture to guess this kind of thinking also prevents colloquials too. For example, being from Kentucky, if I found something insignificant, I could say something like "That doesn't make a lick of difference" but isn't really a type of English that is easily understood globally.

Also, I've noticed there is a Spanish Stack Overflow so it seems like words using the Indian numbering system would be in a Indian Stack Overflow, assuming it will be created.

With regards to using different notation (, vs .), that difference in punctuation doesn't seem different enough to make it hard to guess. I wouldn't have to google something to make a reasonable guess as to what the actually meaning is.

Comment: Considering that there's a whole Stack Overflow site in Japanese, I don't think we'll *ever* see the issue with Japanese counting systems like we would Indian English counting systems.

Comment: Do you mean the Japanese Language Stack Exchange? I'm not seeing a Stack Overflow in Japanese.

Comment: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Thanks! This is cool. I still have to wonder why there isn't one for Indian speakers though . . .

Comment: Because they *are* speaking English...what we're getting hung up on are differences in dialect.

Comment: I'm not so sure those words are English. They seem more like borrowed words put into English. I definitely see your point about not changing code, and agree with you on that part, but changing the word in the problem/description seems okay. A quick google search shows me those words are Indian.

Comment: Indian English is a dialect of English.  I would be willing to accept that lakh and crore are transliterations of their native counting structure into English.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is I don't see those words as a dialect but borrowed from another language so it seems like, if people want to use the Indian language when describing a problem, then there should be a Stack Overflow in that language. I don't think that's unreasonable but it sounds like I'm getting something confused?

Comment: Ah. Your previous response came in before my addendum. But doesn't transliteration make it a borrowed word?

Comment: "Indian" is not a language. And many English words are borrowed (e.g. "entrepreneur"). The meaningful distinction here seems to be whether the word in question is widely understood, rather than its linguistic origins.

Comment: @abeboparebop: Apologies. When I googled those words, the result did come up as Indian so I just repeated what I saw. I'm aware about the question of whether or not the words are widely used. I was illustrating that with the phrase "That doesn't make a lick of difference" in my post. It still seems like lakh and crore would be widely used in a different language specific Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

I argue for a Yes.

The language of this site is English and this should be decisive.
It is necessary to avoid confusion.

Let me give an example from the German language to illustrate that:
In German

- 1 German "million" is 1 English   **million** = 10^6
- 1 German "milliarde" is 1 English **billion** = 10^9
- 1 German "billion" is 1 English **trillion** = 10^12
- 1 German "trillion" is 1 English **quintillion** = 10^18

So without converting these orders of magnitude, there could be a descend into uncertainty.

Comment: French follow the German naming scheme too.

Comment: That is [long scale vs. short scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales).

Answer (score -5):

A counterargument:

If the OP understood that *lakh* or *crore* had different English decimal representations, they'd probably use those as opposed to their own native one.

By changing the number format, you run the risk that the OP won't be able to understand a solution.  It may not matter as much, but it *is* a risk.

Additionally, you don't want overzealous editors removing this from variable names, since it's not up to us to change how their variables are defined.

Comment: If an asker has trouble understanding what `500000` means, I'd hazard a guess that any solution provided would be hard, if not impossible to comprehend due to core differences in how both sides are able to think and communicate. There should be some common ground between asker and answerer for a solution to be valuable.

Comment: If you REALLY want an answer, you want the potential answering party to understand all relevant parts. I would argue that not everybody will lokup what a lakh is, and just not answer the question. it is fine to leave it as-is if your audience is mostly indian, but SO is not afaik.